# Prove that $\frac{d}{dx}(\sin^n x \cos nx) = n \sin^{n-1} x \cos (n+1)x $

Tags: derivatives, trigonometry

> Prove that $\frac{d}{dx}(\sin^n x \cos nx) = n \sin^{n-1} x \cos (n+1)x $

Using product rule, I done-

$\frac{d}{dx}(\sin^n x \cos nx) = (n \sin^{n-1} x \cos x) \cos nx - (n \sin^n x )\sin (nx)$

From the expression, I cannot factorize, there's no common factor. How can I simplify it to get to complete the prove?

Comment: $n \sin^{n-1}x$ is a common factor and $\cos x \cos (nx)-\sin x \sin (nx)=\cos (nx+x)$.

Answer (score 3):

Differentiating $\sin^n x\,\cos nx$ w.r.t. $x$ yields:

$\frac{d}{dx}(\sin^n x\,\cos nx)=(n\sin^{n-1}x\,\cos x)\cos nx-n\sin nx(\sin^n x)$

$\frac{d}{dx}(\sin^n x\,\cos nx)= n\sin^{n-1}x\underbrace{(\cos x\cos nx-\sin x \sin nx)}_{\cos(nx+x)}$

$\frac{d}{dx}(\sin^n x\,\cos nx)=n\sin^{n-1}x\cos(n+1)x$